# How can I multiply values from 2 dropdown lists in asp.net and display the results in a text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a lot of dropdown lists I am building for an insurance app. Each list has a number of options given a multiplier value. My question is how can I multiply these values from separate dropdown lists to give myself a final multiplier value in a textbox? I want to use whatever value is picked from each dropdown list.

The lists are formatted as follows

```
<asp:DropDownList id="points" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.00">0</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.05">1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.10">2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.18">3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.25">4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.32">5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.40">6</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.47">7</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.55">8</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.62">9</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.70">10</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1.77">11</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList id="OtherPolicy" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem value="1.20">Yes</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem value="1.00">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have only been coding for about 2 weeks so hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction. I have not found anything similar in the search here. Thanks guys!

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 for this project, so I can use whatever will work with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember that the values that are going to be stored within your DropDownLists will be strings, so the first step will be converting them to numerical values, which can be done in many ways, but for example purposes, you can use the [`Convert.ToDecimal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
// Convert your Points to a decimal
var pointsValue = Convert.ToDecimal(points.SelectedValue);

// Then convert your selection from your other DropDownList
var policyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(OtherPolicy.SelectedValue);

// Now that you have both of these, you can multiply them to retrieve your result
var result = pointsValue * policyValue;

// Store your result in another TextBox
YourResultTextBox.Text = result.ToString();
```

If you have more DropDownLists or other elements that would need to be part of this calculation, you would just need to ensure that you parse each of their values and then include them in your calculation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, that makes complete sense. What is the simplest way to print the results once those values have been converted and multiplied?

Comment: You could just store the result in a `TextBox` as demonstrated in the example I provided.